# Visually replace div when clicking outside

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function replace( hide, show ) {
                document.getElementById(hide).style.display="none";
                document.getElementById(show).style.display="flex";
            }
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Allerta+Stencil&family=Bebas+Neue&family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;600;700;800&family=Roboto:wght@300;400;700&family=VT323&display=swap');


    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .all_guidebook {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        min-height: 1000px;
        height: auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .title_guidebook {
        position: relative;
        top: 50px;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .disposition_guidebook {
        width: 1100px;
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
        align-items: flex-start;
        top: 55px;
    }

    .navigation {
        width: 286px;
        background: var(--bleu);
        position: relative;
        height: auto;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
        border-radius: 35px;
        margin-right: 15px;
    }

    .navigation .all_links {
        position: relative;
        top: 15px;
    }

    .navigation h1 {
        color: white;
        font: 45px 'Bebas Neue';
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        top: 15px;
    }

    .navigation h2 {
        color: white;
        font: 34px 'Bebas Neue';
        position: relative;
        background: var(--fushia);
        display: flex;
        border-radius: 15px;
        height: 45px;
        padding-top: 2px;
        margin-bottom: 26px !important;
        width: 247px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        top: 20px;
        margin: auto;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .navigation .menu_deroul, #regl {
    display: flex;
    background: blue;
    width: 300px;
    }
    #reglhover {
    display: flex;
    background: blue;
    width: 300px;
    }
#reglhover img, #staffcredshover img, #ctxhover img, #grphover img, #pvrhover img, #syst1hover img, #syst2hover img, #pihover img, #exphover img, #foirehover img {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    top: 5px;
    position: relative;
    left: 7px;
}
.navigation .menu_deroul img {
    float: left;
    left: 7px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.navigation span {
    color: var(--fushiapp);
    margin-right: 3px;
    font: 20px 'Bebas Neue';
}

.navigation h3 {
    color: var(--white);
    font: 20px 'Bebas Neue';
}
.wrap_deroul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    top: -18px;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
.ancres_deroul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-end;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    top: -16px;
    font-weight: 200!important;
    right: 16px;
    font: 16px 'Bebas Neue';
    position: relative;
}
.ancres_deroul ul {
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style: none;
    align-items: flex-end;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.ancres_deroul li {transition: .5s;}
.ancres_deroul li a {
    text-decoration: none!important;
    color: black;
}
.ancres_deroul li:hover {
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu_deroul" id="regl" style="display:flex" >
                    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/cvhdX78/image.png" height="21" width="21" onclick="replace('regl','reglhover')" />
                    <div class="titre_deroul">
                        <span>001.</span>
                        <h3 class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'reglement')" id="defaultOpen">Règlement</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="reglhover" style="display:none">
                    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/cvhdX78/image.png" height="21" width="21" style="cursor:pointer; transform: rotate(135deg); transition: .5s; transition-duration: 2s;" onclick="replace('reglhover','regl')" />
                    <div class="wrap_deroul">
                        <div class="titre_deroul">
                            <span>001.</span>
                            <h3 class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'reglement')">Règlement</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ancres_deroul">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a onclick="scrollWin()">Inscription & RP</a></li>
                                <li style="margin-top: -5px;"><a href="reglement.html#discord" target="myIframe">Discord</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I have this code, it replaces a div by another when clicking on a button.

I want it to close the showed div when clicking outside the div. For example, if the div "reglhover" is showed, I want it to be replaced by the "hide" status (replaced by "regl") when clicking outside the "reglhover" div. And i want it to work for every occurrence (because i use tabs)... But I can't figure out how to do it. Can someone help me? :(

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Only `<li>` can be a child of `<ul>`.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the code. But that doesn't solve my problem unfortunately...
here's the part i modified:
`<ul>
        <li><a onclick="scrollWin()">Inscription & RP</a></li>
        <li style="margin-top: -5px;"><a href="reglement.html#discord" target="myIframe">Discord</a></li>
</ul>`

Comment: Reference for connexo comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul (inside you can have li, template and script. Check for "Permitted content"

Comment: Please create a "working", runnable version in a Stack snippet, which you can create by clicking "Edit" below your post, then the button that resembles `<>`.

Comment: Done! It looks awful but it's a really big code and I cut a little part of it.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
const regl = document.getElementById("regl")
const reglhover = document.getElementById("reglhover")

document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (reglhover.style.display === "flex" && e.target.id != "reglhover") {
        reglhover.style.display = "none"
        regl.style.display = "flex"

    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried, but it doesn't work, now I can't even click on the circle button (it does nothing) :o

Comment: it's because you have your btn inside the div if you want keep it in there you also need condition for it but if you put your btn out of div u can solve your problem

Comment: how do i do the condition for? cause i can't put it outside

Comment: give an id to show btn on img and in the condition say e.target.id != "the id you give it" dont forget to put &&